# How to go to another view by clicking the label

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using asp.net with MVC architecture. I am designing a web page which displays the user's details in table format. I want to click the label and select the entire row and update the details. ie On clicking the label I want to go to another view. How could I do that?

```
<th> @Html.Label("UserName")&nbsp;&nbsp;
<th> @Html.Label("Email") &nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
<th>  @Html.Label("CreatedBy")</th>
</tr>
```

@foreach(var item in Model)
    {
      
    @Html.Encode(item.UserName)
    @Html.Encode(item.Email) 
    @Html.Encode(item.CreatedBy) 
     
    }

Comment: Have you tried anything? show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very extended, but I think this is what you need if you want to have labels that also act like hyperlinks.

```
Html.ActionLink(item.UserName,        // Text shown  
                "YourController",     // Controller Name
                "YourAction",         // Action Method Name
                new { id = item.id }, // Route arguments.
                null)                 // HTML Arguments, ccs class, html Id, etc.
```

For more information you can go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)